# AngularJS $httpBackend expectGET not working

Tags: angularjs, qunit, angular-mock

I am writing QUnit tests for an AngularJS factory. Here's the code for the factory:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.factory('$groupFactory', function($rootScope, $http) {
    return {
        'getAll': function(_callback) {
            $http.get("get/values/from/server", {
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                _callback(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                _callback(data);
            });
        },
    }
});
```

Also see the below Qunit test cases. The test-1 gets the http response from the `$httpBackend` works, but in test-2, it doesn't.

```js
var $scope,
    $rootScope,
    $http,
    $httpBackend,
    $groupFactory,
    injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'App', 'ngMockE2E']),
    init;
init = {
    setup: function() {
        $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        $groupFactory = injector.get('$groupFactory');
        $httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend
            .when('GET', "get/values/from/server")
            .respond({'response': 'success'});
    }
};

module('$groupFactory', init);

// test-1
test("getAll", function() {
    expect(1);
    $groupFactory.getAll(function(data) {
        equal(data.response, 'success', "success casse");
        start();
    });
    stop();
});

// test-2
test("getAll", function() {
    expect(1);
    $httpBackend.expectGET("get/values/from/server").respond(404, {
        response: 'failure'
    });
    $groupFactory.getAll(function(data) {
        equal(data.response, 'failure', "failure casse");
        start();
    });
    stop();
});
```

Any idea why is it not working?

Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kotekar/PgGhN/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$httpBackend.flush()` after `stop()` will work:

```js
stop();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Here's the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kotekar/PgGhN/4/).